# Calculating AWE from mclust package

Tags: r, mclust

Is it possible to calculate the Approximate Weight of Evidence (AWE) from information obtained via the mclust R package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to R [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mclust/versions/1.1-7/topics/awe), you should have access to function `awe(tree, data)` since version R1.1.7.

From the example on the linked page (in case of broken link),

```
data(iris)
iris.m _ iris[,1:4]
awe.val <- awe(mhtree(iris.m), iris.m)
plot(awe.val)
```

Comment: I did try that formula beforehand and it did not recognize the formula. Thought that perhaps the formula was removed, but could be mistaken. Will check again later, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Following the formula from Banfield, J. and Raftery, A. (1993) Model-based Gaussian and non-Gaussian clustering. Biometrics, 49, 803-821. `-2*model$loglik + model$d*(log(model$n)+1.5)` Where model represents the model with number of cluster solutions selected. Keeping this question in the hope that it may help someone in the future.

Comment: Is there a reason not to use the in-built function `awe()`, which is based on the same paper you cite here?